# How to add an column to the same table making the 2 columns in the table unique (query)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an table with the following:

| Name | NamePartner | DateStartCustomer | DateCustomerEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 356 | 01-01-1990 | NULL |
| 356 | 123 | 01-01-1990 | NULL |
| 567 | NULL | 01-01-2020 | NULL |

What I would like to want is an query to add an extra column in this table were I can say that the if Name in the first column is also in the column of NamePartner and the DateCustomerEnd is NULL --> so ongoing relation, then those rows are 1 household. So row 1 and row 2 should be 1 household. I want to give the value of the first columns to that new column

Example:

| Name | NamePartner | UniqueHousehold | DateStartCustomer | DateCustomerEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 356 | 123 | 01-01-1990 | NULL |
| 356 | 123 | 123 | 01-01-1990 | NULL |
| 567 | NULL | 567 | 01-01-2020 | NULL |

UPDATE:

[image: Example]

@Chris Albert
After closely looking at the logic Im seeing duplicates for several rows. This has to do with the ID which is generated of your logic. See picture I added. These are the duplicates im getting. Is there a way to not get duplicates here?

Comment: I would better redesign the table so that doubles are not allowed.

Comment: I think that the need for such a modification suggest that a redesign of the tables used might be necessary

Comment: Its hard to redesign the table, because its coming straight of the software program which is been used to keep track of the customers. I already asked for this or if there is a field somewhere in the source which makes it unique in some way. So for now I'm stuck to do this through sql..

Comment: So then you dont want to add a column as the question asks. What you really want is a query to output the desired result set?

Comment: Yeah, actually that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below will give you the desired result set.

To accomplish this I used [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to generate a unique ID for each row.
This is needed to establish a unique household. Based on your example it appears you want whatever record is first to be the household value. Ideally your source table would have an ID column or [primary key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.ASP) to use for this.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Customer;
CREATE TABLE #Customer
(
    Name INT
    , NamePartner INT
    , DateStartCustomer DATETIME
    , DateCustomerEnd DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #Customer
VALUES
    (123, 356, '01/01/1990', NULL)
    , (356, 123, '01/01/1990', NULL)
    , (567, NULL, '01/01/2020', NULL);

WITH RowNum AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) AS Id
    FROM #Customer
)

SELECT
    C.Name
    , C.NamePartner
    , COALESCE(HH.Name, C.Name) AS UniqueHousehold
    , C.DateStartCustomer
    , C.DateCustomerEnd
FROM
    RowNum           AS C
    LEFT JOIN RowNum AS HH
        ON C.NamePartner = HH.Name
           AND  C.Id > HH.Id;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Customer;
```

Comment: Exactly. Ideally it would have an ID or an BK (Business Key) to identify unique rows. Your solution seems to work. REALLY REALLY APPRECIATE IT! Thanks man!

Comment: Hi Chris, see my comment I made on your logic. I cant seem to add an image in the comment, so I made a new one.

Comment: @Abdio68 You had already accepted this answer. Unaccepting an answer a week later,  after discovering the answer does not meet a requirement you did not post is not the way to approach this. You have a new problem that you should post a new question for.